# Make checkbox, select and input fields inline

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am trying to make a search bar where a green div would be in the middle of the grey one(see http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LRBEvq?editors=1100), and checkboxes, select drop menu, and input field all inline with two buttons - so everything in the same row. I am using Bootstrap to make it responsive but got stuck and can't figure it out.. thank you for all the help!

Here's my html:

```css
.main {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 1202px;
  height: 156px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.formContainer {
  width: 1140px;
  height: 85px;
  background-color: green;
}
button {
  height: 37px;
  width: 160px;
}
.choice {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  height: 37px;
}
.checkbox {
  width: 207px;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
.choice-select {
  width: 173px;
}
.choice-input {
  width: 390px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="main">
      <div class="formContainer">
        <div class="col-md-12">Lorem lorem lorem
          <div class="pull-right">Ipsum lorem ipsum</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row mainContent">
          <!-- mainContent -->
          <div class="col-md-7">
            <!-- main content -->

            <div class="checkbox">
              <span class="choice-details">
                 <label class="checkbox-inline">
                   <input type="checkbox" value="" checked>Lorem
                 </label>
                 <label class="checkbox-inline">
                   <input type="checkbox" value="">Ipsum
                 </label>
               </span>
            </div>
            <div class="choice-select">
              <select class="form-control">
                <option value="one">One</option>
                <option value="two">Two</option>
                <option value="three">Three</option>
                <option value="four">Four</option>
                <option value="five">Five</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="choice-input">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Placeholder text">
            </div>

          </div>
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <button>Lorem ipsum lorem</button>
            <button>Lorem lorem lorem</button>
          </div>
          <!-- end main content -->
        </div>
        <!-- end mainContent -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`display: inline-block;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) for your wrapper divs to behave like inline elements without losing their block properties:

```
.mainContent .checkbox,
.mainContent .choice-select,
.mainContent .choice-input {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

If you also want the buttons to be in the same row, use a `<div class="col-md-12">` for the whole content.

To center your menu bar horizontally, use `margin: 0 auto;`; to center it vertically, [position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) it, apply a `top: 50%;` and [translate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) it back the half of its size in negative y-direction (up):

```
.formContainer {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(0,-50%);
}
```

To make the input text field as long as the remaining space, just set the width of the input the same as its wrapper div:

```
.mainContent .choice-input input {
    width: inherit;
}
```

```css
.main {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 1202px;
  height: 156px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.formContainer {
  width: 1140px;
  height: 85px;
  background-color: green;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
}
button {
  height: 37px;
  width: 160px;
}
.choice {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  height: 37px;
}
.checkbox {
  width: 207px;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
.choice-select {
  width: 173px;
}
.choice-input {
  width: 390px;
}
.mainContent .checkbox,
.mainContent .choice-select,
.mainContent .choice-input {
  display: inline-block;
}
.mainContent .choice-input input {
  width: inherit;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="main">
      <div class="formContainer">
        <div class="col-md-12">Lorem lorem lorem
          <div class="pull-right">Ipsum lorem ipsum</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row mainContent">
          <!-- mainContent -->
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <!-- main content -->

            <div class="checkbox">
              <span class="choice-details">
                <label class="checkbox-inline">
                  <input type="checkbox" value="" checked>Lorem
                </label>
                <label class="checkbox-inline">
                  <input type="checkbox" value="">Ipsum
                </label>
              </span>
            </div>
            <div class="choice-select">
              <select class="form-control">
                <option value="one">One</option>
                <option value="two">Two</option>
                <option value="three">Three</option>
                <option value="four">Four</option>
                <option value="five">Five</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="choice-input">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Placeholder text">
            </div>

            <button>Lorem ipsum lorem</button>
            <button>Lorem lorem lorem</button>
          </div>
          <!-- end main content -->
        </div>
        <!-- end mainContent -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I still have a problem with the green rectangle being in the middle of the grey one..I have tried setting its heigh and width to a certain percentage and position but if I manage to do it it breaks when the window is resized. And I can't get why the input field is not accepting the .choice-input {width: 390px;}, since it should take the whole space all the way to buttons. Thanks for these advices once again, very helpful!

Comment: With "middle" you mean horizontal or vertical center?

Comment: sorry, horizontal and vertical, like box in a box

Comment: so the .formContainer @Andreas

Comment: updated my answer with positioning and width of the input

Comment: yes in Codepen it accepted my change also when I was more specific in selectors:     .choice-input input {width: 390px; height: 38px;}  thank you a lot @Andreas and everyone else. Now I go to figure out how to make it responsive to stack one input under the other when the window is resized

Comment: I am not sure is this was a good way to start this search bar though, I used Bootstrap to make it responsive but only got stuck in its grid, maybe I should try flexbox. Cheers :)

Comment: Hi mate, thanks again for all the help. I decided to use Bootstrap because I wanted to make it easier to get a responsive search bar, and this is what I got for now: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WGKOmB   however there are still issues since it does not scale as supposed, checkboxes on the left get misplaces, input bar gets missing behind, and buttons got stacked one under the other instead of being inline.. i think it's got something to do with pull-right property on the Lorem ipsum, but could not override any props to make it work. Do you perhaps have any suggestion? Thanks a million @Andreas

Comment: If your question is now about responsiveness, just ask a new question :)

Comment: I will, i found a class btn-group http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WGKOmB  which took care of buttons issue. Thank you @andreas

Answer (score 3):

**Horizontal centering:**

For horizontal centering, we want the left and right margin to be equal. The way to do that is to set the margins to 'auto'. This is normally used with a block of fixed width, because if the block itself is flexible, it will simply take up all the available width.

**Vertical centering:**

The essential rules are:

1. *Make the container relatively positioned, which declares it to be a container for absolutely positioned elements.*
2. *Make the element itself absolutely positioned.*
3. *Place it halfway down the container with 'top: 50%'. (Note that 50%' here means 50% of the height of the container.)*
4. *Use a translation to move the element up by half its own height. (The '50%' in 'translate(0, -50%)' refers to the height of the element itself.)*

So your code may seem like this

```
.main {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 1202px;
  height: 156px;
  position: relative;
}

.formContainer {
  width: 1140px;
  height: 85px;
  background-color: green;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
}
```

I hope you solved all the other problems.

Comment: Read about [flex-box](http://css-tricks.com) property It's a new CSS3 property for align boxes flexibly.

Answer (score 1):

Try modifying these rules:

```
.checkbox, .radio {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block; // changed from block to inline-block. Block will take 100% width. To keep elements inline you must use inline-block
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.choice-select {
    width: 173px;
    display: inline-block; // added inline-block
}

.choice-input {
    width: 176px; // reduced width.
    display: inline-block; // added inline-block
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the code below, i have put the html controls in separate divs with bootstrap grid classes to make them inline and added `margin: 0 auto` in `.formContainer` class

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="main">
      <div class="formContainer">
        <div class="col-md-12">Lorem lorem lorem
          <div class="pull-right">Ipsum lorem ipsum</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row mainContent">
          <!-- mainContent -->
          <div class="col-md-7">
            <!-- main content -->
            <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="checkbox">
              <span class="choice-details">
                <label class="checkbox-inline">
                  <input type="checkbox" value="" checked>Lorem
                </label>
                <label class="checkbox-inline">
                  <input type="checkbox" value="">Ipsum
                </label>
              </span>
            </div>
             </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="choice-select">
              <select class="form-control">
                <option value="one">One</option>
                <option value="two">Two</option>
                <option value="three">Three</option>
                <option value="four">Four</option>
                <option value="five">Five</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="choice-input">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Placeholder text">
            </div>
            </div>

          </div>
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <button>Lorem ipsum lorem</button>
            <button>Lorem lorem lorem</button>
          </div>
          <!-- end main content -->
        </div>
        <!-- end mainContent -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>




.main {
    background-color: grey;
    width: 1202px;
    height: 156px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.formContainer {
    width: 1140px;
    height: 85px;
    background-color: green;
  margin: 0 auto;

}

button {
    height: 37px;
    width: 160px;
}

.choice {
    background-color: lightgrey;
    height: 37px;
}

.checkbox {
    width: 207px;
    border: 1px solid white;
}

.choice-select {
    width: 173px;
}

.choice-input {
    width: 390px;
}
```

Comment: thanks! this is what I've got: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WGKOmB   however it's still not responsive since the checkboxes on the left get displaced, same as the search bar... also, the buttons are stacked one under the other, but they should be inline. can you perhaps see where I make the mistake..?  @arsinawaz

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do what you want with only bootstrap markup. I've forked your pen and modified it a little:

http://codepen.io/ugreen/pen/XjBpqX

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-3 text">
                Lorem lorem lorem
                <div class="pull-right">Ipsum lorem ipsum</div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-5">
                <div class="form-inline">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="checkbox" value="" checked>
                        <label>Lorem</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="">
                        <label>Ipsum</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <select class="form-control choice-select">
                            <option value="one">One</option>
                            <option value="two">Two</option>
                            <option value="three">Three</option>
                            <option value="four">Four</option>
                            <option value="five">Five</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Placeholder text">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="button-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-default">Lorem ipsum lorem</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-default">Lorem lorem lorem</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But it might be even better to do something like in the bootstrap docs about navbars:
http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

Comment: Interesting, I will go and try to modify my code to do that, thank you!

Comment: this is what I've got for now: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WGKOmB   but it's still not responsive since the checkboxes on the left get displaced, same as the search bar... also, the buttons are stacked one under the other, but I would like them to be inline with everything else.. @ugreen

Comment: Its not a good idea to set width's in pixels like that on your elements when using bootstrap. Stuff will break apart like you've seen. What are you expecting to happen on smaller screens? Should everything stay in one row? or how should the layout be on table and mobile sizes?

Comment: I would like to stack it one under the other, so check box in one line, select box in the next line etc..